# Creating directive to part of template which is shown after a click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a template with two kind of article-container: Viewer and Editor:

```
<article ng-if="!editor" ng-controller="article">
    <div>Some content</div>
</article>

<article ng-if="editor" ng-controller="article">
    <div mySharedScope></div>
</article>
```

While clicking the button the user can switch between those two container:

```
<button ng-click="editor = !editor" ng-bind="editor ? 'Abort' : 'Edit'"></button>
```

Now I want to create a directive on the second container. So this is what I did:

```
app.directive('mySharedScope', function () {
    return {
        template: 'New content'
    };
});
```

But something is missing, as this doesn't work.
I want to use a directive to do some DOM mainpulation `link: function ($scope, element, attrs) { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, first is that the directive mySharedScope will transform in it's directive definition from camel case

```
<div mySharedScope></div>
```

to a dashes like so

```
<div my-shared-scope></div>
```

After you switch that out, you'll need to make sure you're translcuding content nested inside of your first directive (article), and placing the ng-transclude directive inside of its template.

see [docs for this on angular website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

as a basic implementation of this, i've created a fiddle with the two of your two directives that appropriately switch when a button is triggered. The content is transcluded here, so feel free to cherry pick what you need from it.

https://jsfiddle.net/wvty8rpc/2/

Answer (score 0):

A directive named 'mySharedScope' translates to attribute 'my-shared-scope':

```
<article ng-if="editor" ng-controller="article">
    <div my-shared-scope></div>
</article>
```